# Mounting samba share with root priveleges 12.10

Tags: 12.10, mount, samba, root

How to permanently mount samba share with root priveleges? I've used this [FAQ](https://wiki.ubuntu.com/MountWindowsSharesPermanently) but still getting the same error.
The point is i don't want to send credentials in plane text.

**User credentials file:**

```
username=USER
password=password
domain=sanctuary
```

**smb.conf:**

```
    [global]
    valid users = USER
    browsable = yes
    guest ok = no
    read only = no
    available = yes
    public = no
    writable = yes
    comment = USH
    security = user
    workgroup = Sanctuary
    create mask = 0777
    directory mask = 0777
    unix password sync = yes

    [share]
    comment = archive
    path = /share
    directory mask = 0777
    create mask = 0777
```

**fstab line:**

```
fstab: //192.168.1.50/share /media/share cifs credentials=/etc/samba/user,rw,uid=USER,iocharset=utf8,user,noauto,file_mode=0777,dir_mode=0777 0 0
```

**error:**

```
mount: wrong fs type, bad option, bad superblock on //192.168.1.50/share,
   missing codepage or helper program, or other error
   (for several filesystems (e.g. nfs, cifs) you might
   need a /sbin/mount.<type> helper program)
   In some cases useful info is found in syslog - try
   dmesg | tail  or so
```

From **connect to server** menu in nautilus share mounts fine and dandy, but... again no root.

**Update:**

After simplifying a line in fstab to

```
fstab //192.168.1.50/share /media/share cifs credentials=/etc/samba/user,uid=1000,iocharset=utf8,file_mode=0777,dir_mode=0777 0 0
```

i get the error:

```
mount: only root can mount //192.168.1.50/share on /media/share
```

**Update 2**

Actually i got share mounted with:

```
sudo apt-get install cifs-utils
```

But i still cannot write inside it - is says **Permission denied**

### Update 3 SOLVED

Source of proublem was messed up/non-tweaked permissions

Execute

```
sudo chmod 777 /share
```

on server helped.

Answer (score 1):

I solved it by executing:

```
sudo chmod 777 /share
```

on server.

Comment: I'm going to undelete this because it *is* in fact the answer to the question.